# Facebook: How to publish on own app wall

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have FB application with:

- Application ID
- Application Secret
- Application API Key

How can I publish to own application's wall some text from PHP?
I  don't have facebook's session. I even not logged in to Facebook.

How can I get access_token?
Isn't these 3 keys not enough for this?

Answer (score 0):

I have to use App Login from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Comment: Are you asking or posting an answer?